# Rshiny throws error after publish the app

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, shinydashboard

I implemented a simple stack line graph in Rshiny. The file read from the .csv file added to project folder. The graph is working and displayed fine while running the application from Rstudio. But once the app is published in www.shinyapps.io it is throwing an error `Error in ggplot2: object 'data' not found`. Could anyone help me why this is happening after app deployment. Thanks in advance.

```
ui.R
```

recommendation <- read.csv("recommendation.csv", header = TRUE)

```
server.R


output$serviceCostEfficiency <- renderPlot({
    data <- read.csv("pie.csv", header = TRUE)

    ggplot() + geom_area(data=data, aes(x=year, y=cost, fill=z)) + 
      guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))

  })
```

Comment: From ui.R and server.R I guess you have two scripts. If so, you need to read the csv file in the server.R file not in the ui. Before upload your App to shinyapps.io try to run the app using `Run App`  to make sure all dependencies are available to the app.

Comment: @A.Suliman great. As you suggested when i added the data reading in server.R it is working fine after publishing. But recommendation which read in ui.R is working fine even after publishing. The problem arises only for data. could you please throw some light on this part. Also please answer the question so I can accept it